# how does android handles and prioritize xml attribute overlaps between API versions

Tags: android, xml

I have a button on my app. I want this button to have a simple animation when clicked and a custom background color. Android button has by default a serie of animations when the button is clicked.

There are 3 methods that I tried that changes the color of the button. The "best" one is

`android:backgroundTint`

However it is only available from API 21 and higher. I consider it the best one because it keeps the default android onclick animation (shadow, color change, etc).

As it is only available from API 21 I added the line

`android:background`

The problem is that this attribute does not keep the default android onClick animation. When the 2 attributes are put together the *background* attribute is taking over the *backgroundTint* one.

Last stuff I did was to set up a drawable that will change the color of the button on click. The drawable is put in the *android:background* attribute. It is working fine however this time if the 2 attributes, *background* and *backgroundTint* are present, the background drawable is not taking action, acting like a background attribute set up without selector.

From that I would like to know how does android handles the attributes overlap in the different API versions?

Comment: I think you can define that with a custom background shape. It provides you with the pressed state

Comment: Yeah that is what I did, the third point of the post, but when coupled with the backgroundTint attribute, the selector in the cutsom model does not work, so I would like to know how android handles it when xml attributes are overlaping in term of funcrionnalities (here background and backgroundtint)